# Point server ipaddress to subdomain name

Tags: dns, apache2, shared-hosting

I am using apache2 server and this is my config file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName  139.59.0.235
            ServerAdmin sreeram.juluru@gmail.com
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/linQ/app.wsgi
            <Directory /var/www/linQ/app/>
                    WSGIProcessGroup linQ
                    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/linQ/app/static
            <Directory /var/www/linQ/app/static/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

My domain(linq.store) is managed by GoDaddy. How do I now point a subdomain(jarvis.linq.store) to my server ip address?
Tried few solutions, all I was trying to do was forward jarvis.linq.store to 139.59.0.235. 
How to exactly map my server address to subdomain, so the url always stays as jarvis.linq.store.
Do I need to make any changes in /etc/hosts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go to GoDaddy and edit your DNS corresponding to your domain name linq.store.

In your DNS configuration you have to add a "A Record" (Connects an IP Address to a host name) in order to make jarvis.ling.store to point to 139.59.0.235, I don't know GoDaddy interface but this link should help :

https://fr.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238

The DNS edit will take time to be propagated on the network, there are several ways to verify it (like in a terminal : ping jarvis.ling.store => this must display 139.59.0.235 when it is propagated).

Then in your apache config file you should have this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  jarvis.ling.store
    ServerAdmin sreeram.juluru@gmail.com
    ...
```

This config file must be on the apache server which is identified by the IP address 139.59.0.235

On your apache server, you will have to reload apache service, or restart apache service in order the changes made in config files are taken in account. If there is no error when you reload or restart that should be ok.